# How do I know when geometry (SCNNodes) are at the edge of the view?

Tags: ios, scenekit

I want to do an endless parallax style background with SceneKit, but I don't think I understand quite how to detect when a mesh is "off camera".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scene renderer (only the view on iOS) can check if an object is inside the frustum (the shape of what is viewable) from a specific point of view (like a camera) using `isNodeInsideFrustum:withPointOfView:`

This checks if the bounding box of the node is inside of the frustum (ignoring if it's obscured by something else). I.e. the node is in the viewable region but it's not guaranteed to be visible on the screen.

To check if something is "off camera", you can check if it's outside the viewable region for that camera (here I've assumed that the camera is the scene view's point of view):

```
BOOL isOffCamera = ![yourSceneView isNodeInsideFrustum:theNodeToCheck
                                       withPointOfView:yourSceneView.pointOfView];
```